# Why sometimes init process read /dev/initctl return -1?

Tags: linux

We use sysvinit to build our system. When I input `poweroff` command, sometimes system has no any response.
I did some investigation, and found that in the function `check_init_fifo()` of init, the line:

```
n = read(pipe_fd, &request, sizeof(request));
```

sometimes it return -1, and the error code is `EAGAIN`.

I modified the init code, and let it retry for 5 times when the error code is EAGAIN, but not work well.

Does anyone know why sometimes `read /dev/initctl` return -1?  How to resolve this?
 Thanks.

Comment: Read the [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [error(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/error.3.html) man pages.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the root cause. There is a lxc container running in our system, and the devfs is shared between this container and host. The init processes of container and host can read the /dev/initctl, but sometimes the init of host is not the first one who read the /dev/initctl.